# Can you implement lazy array access in QtScript?

Tags: javascript, qt, lazy-evaluation, qtscript

Is it possible to implement a QObject for use in QtScript which overloads [] to implement lazy array population?

I want to implement something like this:

```
var bar = foo["bar"];
```

and have the value be lazily calculated in C++ code. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. `bar` will be available as a property in the QScriptValue object which represents `foo`.

If you want the calculation to happen automatically, you possibly have to subclass `QScriptClass` and re-implement the `property()` accessor function.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to implement operator[] in the QObject that you expose to QtScript? Easier to answer if you also include some code.